# Запрос к /oauth/token завершается с ошибкой с invalid_request

Tags: python, curl

ребята,

Я разрабатываю скрипт на python:

```
import requests
 

 
url = 'myurl'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'api_key':'my api_key',
    'email':'my_mail',
}

 
r = requests.post(url, headers = headers)

print(r.json())
```

по сути  этот скрипт должен писать данный код в терминал:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d 'email=mymail&api_key=my api_key' 'my_url'
```

если прям так и писать в терминал то это работает, но если пользоватся скриптом то выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the "username" parameter.'}
```

откуда там взялся параметр username я вообще незнаю

писать     'username': 'my_mail'
я пробовал но не моголго

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

data = 'email=mymail&api_key=my api_key'

response = requests.post('http://my_url', headers=headers, data=data)
```

https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка: данные, которые должны передаваться в теле запроса, вы используете в `headers`.

То есть запрос `curl`  и в `python` не эквивалентны

```py
import requests
 
url = 'myurl'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = {
    'api_key':'my api_key',
    'email':'my_mail',
}
 
r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data=data)

print(r.json())
```

`Post` запрос подразумевает наличие данных, которые передаются в теле, о чем  вам и говорит флаг `-d` в запросе `curl`